# Unable to change the background of the text area in bootstrap v5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I've tried different ways in my custom style.css file to change the background color of the bootstrap text area without success.

```
<div class="col-6">
        <label for="example_ta" class="form-label">example text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="example" id="example_ta" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
#example_ta
textarea#exampleta 
textarea.form-control
```

But haven't been able to get the color to change from white.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to change the styles of a bootstrap-element.

1. Add bootstrap-class [`bg-{color}`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/background/#background-color) to your element
2. Style the element with custom CSS-rules

```css
#example_ta2 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <label for="example_ta" class="form-label">You can change the background-color with a bootstrap-class, e.g. <code>bg-primary</code>...</label>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-primary" name="example" id="example_ta" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
      <label for="example_ta2" class="form-label">...or change it with custom CSS.</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="example2" id="example_ta2" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, note that depending on how you embedded your stylesheets and what your selectors as well as css-rules are, some styles might get overwritten by bootstrap (see below example).

```css
#example_ta3 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#example_ta4 {
  background-color: orange!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <label for="example_ta3" class="form-label">Note that custom bootstrap-classes usually overwrite your custom CSS...</label>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-danger" name="example3" id="example_ta3" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
      <label for="example_ta4" class="form-label">...unless you overwrite them with <code>!important</code> or by having a more precise selector.</label>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-danger" name="example4" id="example_ta4" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that you can [customize the bootstrap-variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/) to change the styles for all bootstrap-components and -styles.